# Discrete lamp dimmer circuit: how to choose component values?

Tags: dimmer, lamp

[image: Dimmer circuit using thyristor]

As you can see, the VAR is 500K Ohms, the capacitor is 100nF. (AC voltage = 220V, freq = 50Hz)

I already built this circuit and it works perfectly. Can anyone show me how those values were chosen? Can I use other values, like the VAR = 50K, the cap = some value?

Comment: The power dissipated by a 50k potmeter will be pretty high, 1W or more, which is probably too much for standard potmeters. I don't particularly like the circuit because it has 230V across the potmeter, surely many aren't rated for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the 50k value here is my idea. I'm wondering why people found 500k Ohms and 100nF used in this circuit. Which formula they used in this circuit to find those values

Comment: RC=.5M*.1u=50ms for 10ms half sine is what you have. Trigger current is asymmetric , lowest, if both positive, did u want to add 1A diode bridge? That will lower load current, by factor of 10 and thus Rvar power so bigger R values can be used and less flicker from asymm. Use Ohms Law with Sawtooth on V Diac to Triac load of Vbe*2 to ensure triac gate current is in range

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm learing SCRs and triacs, the simplifier version of this circuit is using SCR to control the lamp in positive phases - may be it's easier to understand how thyristors work. Can you show me some more documents about this case?

Comment: @Joe u used RC formula. So suppose we not mentioned the power dissipated of the components, I take the value of R = 50k and C = 1u to get the value RC = 50ms, is this ok for the circuit working?

Comment: Yes that works but burns out pot at low R. As RC goes to <1ms. So no it fails. Sensitive gate triac needed with high R only but RC from .1 to 50ms for wide phase angle control with log taper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit triggers the triac when the voltage across the switch, after going through the RC circuit made from the rheostat and the 100nF capacitor, exceeds  the diac trigger voltage. After that, the triac triggers and the voltage drops to a volt or two, so the power dissipated by the rheostat is low. It can have mains voltage across it, but only when it is turned to maximum.

Because the triac turning on "resets" the capacitor, this circuit has an annoying snap-on hysteresis effect around where it first turns on (minimum brightness).

The rheostat resistance is chosen high enough that it doesn't overheat with mains voltage across it. Say 0.25W is acceptable, then R \$\ge \frac{230^2}{0.25} \$~= 200K. 50K would dissipate more than 1W, and would require a 1uF capacitor, neither of which is desirable, but not impossible if the pot is suitably rated.

The capacitor is chosen to give an appropriate delay for 1/2 cycle of the mains. The math gets a bit messy because it's a sine wave input, but 100nF is about right for a 500K pot on 230V. Illustration from GE SCR manual.

[image]

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does a goos job of calculating the time domain voltage across the capacitor of an RC circuit driven by a sine wave source:http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+%281%2F%28s+C%29%29%2F%28R+%2B+1%2F%28s+C%29%29%C3%97%28%28V+omega%29%2F%28s%5E2+%2B+omega%5E2%29%29&x=0&y=0

Comment: Can you show me the simplifier formula, like using sin cos... ? Thanks so much